# Alternative to while statement

Tags: c++, dll, com, atl, visual-studio-2019

I'm dealing with an eye tracker. This is a device that watches the user's pupils. 
They have a really basic example, and in their sample code, they wait for callbacks this way:

```
int is_running = 1000; // in this sample, exit after some iterations
while( --is_running > 0 )
{
    error = tobii_wait_for_callbacks( NULL, 1, &device );
    assert( error == TOBII_ERROR_NO_ERROR || error == TOBII_ERROR_TIMED_OUT );

    error = tobii_device_process_callbacks( device );
    assert( error == TOBII_ERROR_NO_ERROR );
}
```

I need to encapsulate their sample code in an ATL COM DLL, and I wonder what I could use if I want to run the code as long as the DLL is alive. 
I don't want to use a fixed value like they did.

Do I have to use an endless while loop?

I come from event driven Visual Basic and while statements sound like something that blocks other things while they're being executed.

The full (short) C++ code can be inspected [here](https://developer.tobii.com/consumer-eye-trackers/stream-engine/getting-started/).

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: `while (!terminated)` and then you just have to figure out how to set `terminated` to `true` when you want to kick out. You'll still be at the mercy of however long `tobii_wait_for_callbacks` waits for a callback.

Comment: @user4581301 Can I still call voids from the consuming app while the ATL DLL processes the while statement?

Comment: @tmighty you can if the `while` loop is run in a separate thread

Comment: Can you consider an ATL COM exe instead of a DLL?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Can you point me to a link on how to do that?